# How do I configure LESS with Aurelia ESnext Easy-Webpack?

Tags: less, aurelia, easy-webpack

I'm trying to configure [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) support in the [Aurelia ESnext-Webpack Skeleton starter kit](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack), and having pulled in a Less-based framework, I'm seeing the following warning when I run `npm start`:

```
WARNING in ./~/css-loader!./~/spectre.css/spectre.less
Module build failed: Unknown word (1:1)
> 1 | // Copyright 2016 Spectre.css
    | ^
  2 | // Licensed under MIT Open Source
  3 |
  4 | // Core variables

 @ ./src ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./~/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/commonjs/aurelia-loader-webpack.js
 @ multi aurelia
```

[image]

Here's the configuration I'm using:

```
/* ./webpack.config.babel.js */
...
import html from '@easy-webpack/config-html'
import less from '@easy-webpack/config-less'
import css from '@easy-webpack/config-css'
...
let config = generateConfig(
  ...
  html(),
  less({ filename: 'styles.css', allChunks: true, sourceMap: false }),
  css({ filename: 'styles.css', allChunks: true, sourceMap: false }),
  ...
)
...
```

However, despite the warning it appears to be working - `styles.css` contains all of the `less` assets when inspected in the browser.

**Have I configured [easy-webpack/config-less](https://github.com/easy-webpack/config-less) correctly?**

**If so, how do stop the warning message from showing?**